# Symfony2 basic URL routing issue

Tags: controller, query-string, url-routing, symfony

I'm aware that my question is very...plain and simple, but I'll ask it anyway: hope that someone can give me a hint.

I'm rewriting a PHP web-application using Symfony2. My need is to perform CRUD operations on database objects (which have a primary key and other two fields, called `field1` and `field2`)

In my old web-app I used to recall this URL:

```
  http://myhost/updateProduct.php?id=foo&field1=value1&field2=value2
```

to invoke the `updateProduct.php` script to update the object having id=foo, setting value1 for field1 and value2 for field2.

Now I'm willing to use a Symfony2 controller to do that job...I wonder which routing should I set up for that. My controller is `ProductController` and it embeds a `updateAction($id,$field1,$field2)` method.

I tried with something like (yml syntax):

```
myBundle_update:
    pattern:  /product/update/{id}/field1={value1}&field2={value2}
    defaults: { _controller: TestMyBundle:Product:update }
```

but it's not working.

So my question is: I'm mistaking the routing syntax (and if so, which is the correct one)? Or is there something I am missing about how to properly split request parameters to controllers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want your route to look something like this:

```
pattern:    /product/update/{id}/{value1}/{value2}
```

This way just just invoke /product/update/1/fieldValue1/fieldValue2 to update the product.

I'm not sure, but probably the routing has some problems with your route defining an & in its route.

Update:
Ah, the problem lies most probably in the fact that you don't have a / between your two values.
Symfony2 uses the regex [^/]+ as standard regex for a parameter.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

Comment: The pattern you mention is valid, and I've been thinking about using it. But I wanted to use some kind of "user-friendly" URLs where field names could be specified, one way or another. Isn't there any way to escape the & and = characters in Symfony2 routing?

Comment: you could try something to add a requirement to the pattern like this

requirements:
    value1: "[^&]+"

So it would stop searching when it finds the first &

Comment: & and = can be percent encoded (%26 and %3D respectively) and the route will not break, but the Symfony2 router will not match them (as it will try to match %26 and %3D literally).